# Measuring speed and distance from Accelerometer datas

Tags: c++, arduino, accelerometer, physics, sensors

I am using a LSM9DS0 sensor with 9DOF (Accelerometer, Gyro, Magnetometer)

After receiving the acceleration from X, Y, Z axes (in G) , i do the following steps

Let us say the Accelerations are AccelX_Avg, AccelY_Avg, AccelZ_Avg in the X, Y, Z directions

```
Accel_Avg = (sqrt(AccelX_Avg*AccelX_Avg + AccelY_Avg*AccelY_Avg + AccelZ_Avg*AccelZ_Avg)) * 9.88888;
```

Then i calculate the speed and distance

```
if (i_offset_distance == 0) { // calculate the speed(V1) and distance(D1) for first instant 
      i_offset_distance = i_offset_distance + 1 ;
      Serial.println("\nFirst is done \n");
      Measured_Velocity_1 = (Accel_Avg* dt_ODR_A);
      Distance_covered_1 = (Measured_Velocity*dt_ODR_A) + (0.5*Accel_Avg*dt_ODR_A*dt_ODR_A);
      }

      else{

      Measured_Velocity = Measured_Velocity_1 + (Accel_Avg* dt_ODR_A); // V2 = V1 + Accelration * Dt 
      Measured_Velocity_1 = Measured_Velocity;
      Distance_covered = (Measured_Velocity*dt_ODR_A) + (0.5*Accel_Avg*dt_ODR_A*dt_ODR_A) + Distance_covered_1;
      Distance_covered_1 = Distance_covered;
      i_offset_distance = i_offset_distance + 1;

      }
```

It gives me everytime incremntal values of velocity and distance travelled, how ever i am expecting, when the sensor would be at rest Acceleration (0,0,g), the velocity should be zero. Also if it is not moving, it should give distance_covered to be also 0.

How can i get speed and total_distance covered correctly?

Any form of advise through code implementation, concept, algorithm would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your native language, and how well do you understand integral calculus?

Comment: German. I had studied before in my school. @Beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use the 6 point calibration Method for Calibration of accelerometer sensor.
https://chionophilous.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/accelerometer-calibration-ii-simple-methods/
http://sailboatinstruments.blogspot.in/2011/09/improved-magnetometer-calibration-part.html

This uses Magneto software for calibration. The basic concept is to fit the values of (AccelX_Avg, AccelY_Avg, AccelZ_Avg) on a sphere of radius 9.8 using bias and sensitivity. This will ensure that there is no accelerometer values during rest state of IMU and distance remains almost zero.
But because you are double integrating, the distance will always have some drift, so I would prefer to apply either Kalman or DCM filter for filtering out the high frequency accelerometer noises and long term gyroscope drift....In case of any doubt, do comment below

Comment: Hi Aakash, SOrry for the late reply. 

" But because you are double integrating, the distance will always have some drift, so I would prefer to apply either Kalman or DCM filter for filtering out the high frequency accelerometer noises and long term gyroscope drift."

Do you mean exactly the same way as described here [reference: Freescale]
[link](http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3397.pdf?fsrch=1&sr=2)